# Why is exp used in encoder of VAE instead of using the value of standard deviation alone?

Tags: machine-learning, autoencoders, variational-autoencoder, notation

There's one VAE example here: 
https://towardsdatascience.com/teaching-a-variational-autoencoder-vae-to-draw-mnist-characters-978675c95776.

And the source code of encoder can be found at the following URL: https://gist.github.com/FelixMohr/29e1d5b1f3fd1b6374dfd3b68c2cdbac#file-vae-py.

The author is using $e$ (natural exponential) for calculating values of the embedding vector:

$$z = \mu + \epsilon \times e^{\sigma}$$

where $\mu$ is the mean, $\epsilon$ a small random number and $\sigma$ the standard deviation.

Or in code

```
z  = mn + tf.multiply(epsilon, tf.exp(sd))
```

It's not related to the code (practical programming), but why using natural exponential instead of:

$$z = \mu + \epsilon \times \sigma$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the source code, the author defines `sd` by

```
sd       = 0.5 * tf.layers.dense(x, units=n_latent)
```

which means that $\operatorname{sd}\in \mathbb{R}^n$.
In particular, the support over `sd` includes negative numbers, which is something we want to avoid.
Since standard deviations are always nonnegative, we can exponentiate to get us in the correct domain.
This is a case where the variable is inappropriately named.
Here, `sd` is not the standard deviation itself but rather the *logarithm* of the standard deviation. This allows it to be predicted as the output of a layer in a neural network, so extracting the predicted value of the standard deviation would require exponentiation.

Comment: hm yes, tks, that `sd` is `ln` of sd, not sd